# Vuejs splice duplicate

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuex

I am building a editor where you have a duplicate function to duplicate your elements. The duplicate function works the following

```
let newDataB = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.data.content[headerId].content[columnId].content[blockId]));
//Generate a new id
newDataB.id = shortid.generate();

//Generate new id's if the block has childs
if(typeof newDataB.data.data !== 'undefined') {
  if(typeof newDataB.data.data[0] !== 'undefined') {
    newDataB.data.data.forEach((value, key) => {
      newDataB.data.data[key].id = shortid.generate();
    });
  }
}

//blockId is a var which holds the current index of the block in the array
state.data.content[headerId].content[columnId].content.splice(blockId + 1,0,newDataB);
```

This code is located in my store this updates the store and sends it back to my vue application

Now the following things happens

**One**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4nrc9dx0kk2lx02/2017-12-04%2015.55.06.gif?dl=0

this line of code changed in the video version

```
//blockId is a var which holds the current index of the block in the array
state.data.content[headerId].content[columnId].content.splice(blockId - 1,0,newDataB);
```

as you can see blockId + 1 is in changed to blockId - 1

**Two**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ees7f7s9plxb3y/2017-12-04%2015.55.53.gif?dl=0

now the code is the following

```
//blockId is a var which holds the current index of the block in the array
state.data.content[headerId].content[columnId].content.splice(blockId,0,newDataB);
```

as you can see blockId + 1 is in changed to blockId

**Three**

https://www.dropbox.com/s/k316sw85ewkgfhc/2017-12-04%2015.56.47.gif?dl=0

What wired is in this example is that the problem is happening after 2 times duplication

the code is the following

```
//blockId is a var which holds the current index of the block in the array
```

`state.data.content[headerId].content[columnId].content.splice(blockId + 1,0,newDataB);`

as you can see blockId + 1 is now blockId + 1

**Some last notes**

The problem is solved when I save my state and then refresh my page. I do not know why this is happening (I want it to work without refreshing the page). What I want to make is that the user can duplicate content but still is able to edit the duplicated content this is now not possible.

Thank you very much for reading this and I hope you can help me :)

**How the resizer works**

The resizer is a component which edit's its data with the tooltip component that looks the following

1. The image Element requests a tooltip (done with commit in vuex)
2. The tooltip shows on top of the image element and renders the resizer bar
3. On change the tooltip commits the new data to vuex so vuex can pass it back to vue for rendering the changes

Code of the on change resizer

```
            this.$store.commit(types.CHANGE_BLOCK, {
                headerId: this.headerid,
                columnId: this.columnid,
                blockId: this.blockid,
                blockChildId: 0,
                properties: {
                    height: (this.value < 10 ? this.value + 10 : this.value)
                }
            });
```

Code of the function in vuex

```
                        //ADJUSTMENTS BLOCK
                        _.each(data[Object.keys(data)[4]], function(value, key) {
                            state.data[domain][headerId].content[columnId].content[blockId].data[Object.keys(data)[4]][key] = value;
                        });
```

Comment: I think we need to see some code for the resizer, in particular how it is attached to what it resizes.

Comment: I am going to add it

Comment: I would suggest not using splice, it can be very unpredictable. Instead, use `slice()` and `concat()` to achieve the same result. They are both pure functions and will help you at least rule out some sections of code that seem problematic

Answer (score 1):

When you generate `newDataB`, you give it a new `id`, but your size-committing code doesn't use that; it seems to use `headerId`, `columnId`, and `blockId` to figure out which block(s) get updated. Since those are cloned values, the original and the new will be updated.

Maybe that `id` is supposed to be `blockId`?